# In a SSAS Hierarchy I only want the active records

Tags: ssas, hierarchy

I have a Program - Project hierarchy, a program has many projects, when I update, my project dimension, and reload the projects again, but setting the current attribute to 0 for old projects, and to 1 for new projects.
My problem is that when I see my Program - project hierarchy, I see both the old projects and the new ones, how do I tell to ssas that I only want the current projects
Thanks a lot in advance
Anabel

Comment: I would add e. g. a where condition to the MDX statement like `WHERE [Project].[Current].[1]`.

Comment: I want to fix it in the analysis service, the front-end only reads the hierarchy from the analysis service

Comment: If you do not want inactive projects to appear in the cube, then do not load them: base your dimension on a view that exclude these via a where condition like `where current = 1`, or implement this in a named query in the DSV instead of a database view.

Comment: I implemented a named query and I didn't work, the hierarchy still shows the old projects

Comment: If you click "Explore data" on your named query, does it show the old projects? Then, there is something wrong with your SQL in the named query. Otherwise, did you use this named query as base for your dimension? Did you re-process the dimension/database?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter on the front-end (e.g. Excel, custom tool using MDX, etc)

Without filter:

[image: unfiltered results]

With filter:

[image: filtered results]